# Many to many join table not updated in Active admin

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models Destination and Package. A package may have multiple Destinations and Destination may contain multiple Packages. In order to maintain the relationship, I have a table called packages_in_destinations. While I tried to insert destination from package form in active admin, it doesn't show up any errors but the packages_in_destinations table is not updated. I am using MySQL for the database.

```
# app/admin/package.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Package do
  permit_params :package_id, :package_title, :description, :featured_image, :duration, :meta_description, :meta_keywords, :published, :package_categories_id, :destinations_id

  form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
      f.inputs "Package Details" do
        f.input :destination_id, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => Destination.all.collect {|destination| [destination.destination_title, destination.id]}
        end
    f.actions
  end
end

# app/models/package.rb file
class Package < ApplicationRecord
  validates_uniqueness_of :package_title, scope: :package_title
  validates :package_title, :description, :package_categories_id, :presence => true
  belongs_to :package_category
  has_and_belongs_to_many :packages_in_destinations
  has_many :destinations, through: :packages_in_destinations
end

# app/models/destination.rb file
class Destination < ApplicationRecord
  validates_uniqueness_of :destination_title, scope: :destination_title
  validates :destination_title, :description, :altitude, :geolocation, :presence=>true
  has_and_belongs_to_many :packages_in_destinations
  has_many :packages, through: :packages_in_destinations
end

# app/models/packages_in_destination.rb
class PackagesInDestination < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :destinations, foreign_key: :destination_id, class_name: 'Destination'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :packages, foreign_key: :package_id, class_name: 'Package'
end
```

the relationship between two table has been created from migration file

```
class CreatePackagesInDestinations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    create_join_table :packages, :destinations, table_name: :packages_in_destinations do |t|
    t.index :package_id
    t.index :destination_id
    t.timestamps
  end

  def down
    drop_table :packages_in_destinations
  end
end
```

another migration file is created to add a primary key to the table

```
class AddingPrimaryInPackaesInDestination < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :packages_in_destinations, :id, :primary_key
  end
end
```

so from all these things no error has been shown but packages saves in packages table but not inserted relationship in the `packages_in_destinations` table. Please, somebody, suggest what's missing and what's wrong with these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either use `has_and_belongs_to_many` or `has_many :through`. Don't use both at the same time.

1) Example with `has_and_belongs_to_many`. In this case, you can remove `PackagesInDestination` model:

```
# app/models/package.rb file
class Package < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :destinations, join_table: :packages_in_destinations
end

# app/models/destination.rb file
class Destination < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :packages, join_table: :packages_in_destinations
end

# app/models/packages_in_destination.rb
# removed
```

2) Example with `has_many :through`:

```
# app/models/package.rb file
class Package < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  has_many :packages_in_destinations
  has_many :destinations, through: :packages_in_destinations
end

# app/models/destination.rb file
class Destination < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  has_many :packages_in_destinations
  has_many :packages, through: :packages_in_destinations
end

# app/models/packages_in_destination.rb
class PackagesInDestination < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :destination
  belongs_to :package
end
```

Comment: @SudeepGhimiray you welcome. If my answer did help you please consider marking it as accepted by clicking on checkmark left to the answer